# Can't get "text replacement" working on a simple div, why?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm doing something stupid ... but, I just can't see it. I'm trying to move my text offscreen to accommodate screen readers -- and use the background image for presentation

```
<div class="memberstatus-clubmember">
    Clubmember
</div>


.memberstatus-clubmember {
   background: transparent url(/memberStatus/clubmember.png) no-repeat 0 0;
   display:block;
   width:193px; /* width of image */
   height:15px; /* height of image */
   text-indent:-999999px; 
}
```

Comment: Is that CSS within a <style> tag, or in a css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `position: absolute;`

```
.memberstatus-clubmember {
   background: transparent url(/memberStatus/clubmember.png) no-repeat 0 0;
   display:block;
   width:193px; /* width of image */
   height:15px; /* height of image */
   text-indent:-999999px; 
   position: absolute;
}
```

**This should help:**

- [CSS text-indent: An Excellent Trick To Style Your HTML Form](http://aext.net/2010/02/css-text-indent-style-your-html-form/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure without seeing what you're getting.

You could try setting `overflow: hidden; text-indent: 200px;`

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works fine by itself. There must be a conflict elsewhere in your stylesheet or HTML.

One word of advice though- what is the text "Clubmember" for?  You may want to consider changing the div to a H1 or similar tag.  You can still style it appropriately, since you already have a "display:block".